# how to duplicate item on a map (not in the end)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to duplicate an existing item on the map. I have a map of images, Let say I have [1,2,3] and I want to clone or duplicate 2 so I will get [1,2,2,3], how can I do that?

I have images gallery. I have a 'clone button' that if you want to clone an image you will get the same image up next. 
for example: (flower, car, cat, water) and than clone 'car' will get us (flower, car, car, cat, water).

```
//images- is the current map.
  // dto- is the item I am searching
  cloneImage(dto) {
    const { images } = this.state;
    let newImages = [];
    newImages = images.map((image) => {
      if (image.id === dto.id) {
        // this also didn't work- images.map(image).push(dto);
       return newImages.concat([image, image]);
      } else {
        return image;
      }
    });
    this.setState({
      images: newImages
    });
  }
```

So, I found my item in the map, but when I tried to duplicate I used concat but instead of clone the existing to [1,2,2,3] I got [1, [2,2] , 3].

Comment: When you say 'map', do you mean array?

Comment: You cannot use the `.map` function on an array in the way you're trying to, to add items. What you want to do is find the array where you want to add the item, and do a .splice to add the item

Comment: Use this documentation on how to add an item to an array at a given index: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Comment: @TKoL I am a little bit confused because it is a map but when I debug it looks like an array

Comment: If it's a map, ie created by `new Map()`, then it will not have a `.map` function on it. I'm sure it's an array

Comment: The `.map` function on an array doesn't output a map, it outputs another array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing the ordering is important? You could always just flatten the array at the end? Perhaps something a little something like this.

```
cloneImage(id) {
  const { images } = this.state;

  this.setState({
    images: images.map(image => {
      return image.id === id
        ? [image, JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(image))]
        : image;
    }).flat();
  });
}
```

Comment: This will cause `image` to be a reference to the other image object, not a copy, be careful mate

Comment: @MosèRaguzzini he never expressed any need for it to not be a copy

Comment: I think It's a good practice to have individual elements and not references in an array. Anyway using map() for this task is extremely wrong. In fact you have to flatten the array in the end.

Answer (score 1):

The map function always returns one item, in your example, a single "image" or an array.

You might want to look into forEach instead.

```
cloneImage(oldArray, dto) {
  const newArray = []

  oldArray.forEach(image => {
    if (image.id === dto.id) {
      newArray.push(image)
    }

    newArray.push(image)
  }

  return newArray
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a nice short method using `Array.prototype.reduce`

```
cloneImage(dto) {
    const { images } = this.state;
    const newImages = images.reduce((acc,curr)=> curr.id===dto.id?[...acc,curr,curr]:[...acc,curr] ,[])
    this.setState({images: newImages}
  }
```

Comment: Have you tested this? I don't think this will work, as it will add the matching item twice, sure, but the array won't have any other non-matching items.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this simpler solution, you do not need `map()`

```js
cloneImage(dto) {
    const { images } = this.state;
    const imageIndex = images.find(
      element => element.id === dto.id
    );
    const elemnentClone = JSON.stringify(images[imageindex]);
    this.setState({
      images: [...images, elementClone]
});
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Webber has a good answer, but you can also splice an element into an array with this code:

```
cloneImage(dto) {
    const { images } = this.state;
    let newImages = images.slice(0); // to clone the array
    let index = images.findIndex(image => image.id === dto.id);
    let imageToClone = images[index];

    newImages.splice(index, 0, imageToClone);

    this.setState({
        images: newImages
    });
}
```